# Calculate percentage in integer of a column in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql-server

I have just started experimenting how to calculate the percentage of a row. This is the code I write.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ServiceName
COUNT(serviceID) AS Services
FROM Tester_DW
WHERE DateToday=20150410
GROUP BY ServiceName
```

How can calculate the percentage of the column Services above, and have the percentage in integer? Is it easier to calculate the percentage of the code example if I put my query result in a #temp table and calculate the percentage from the #temp or is it possible to calculate the percentage in integer% on the fly?

ADDED:Output sketch

```
ServiceName|Services| % of Total
--------------------------------
TV-cable   |  4500  |   40%
--------------------------------
Mobile BB  |  3000  |   10%
--------------------------------
MOBILE wifi|    20  |    5%
--------------------------------
```

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: How did you get TV-cable as 40% ? is this computed against the total number of rows in `GROUP` without the date filter?

Comment: that 40% is just  a made up number for this sketch. Basically, whatever the total amount of services adds upto, when calculate percentage on that for the services.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to get it right, because you should deal with the sum of rounded integer percentage to get it 100% in total.

Using [Largest Remainder Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method)

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ServiceName, 
        COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS [Percent], 
        FLOOR(COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) AS [IntPercent], 
        COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () % 1 AS [Remainder]
    FROM Tester_DW
    GROUP BY ServiceName
)
SELECT ServiceName, IntPercent + CASE WHEN Priority <= Gap THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IntPercent
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Remainder DESC) AS Priority, 100 - SUM(IntPercent) OVER () AS Gap FROM x
) data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    ServiceName, 
    Count(ServiceName) as Services, 
    (Count(ServiceName)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From Tester_DW)) as [% of total]
From Tester_DW
Group By ServiceName
```

You simply divide the count of a single service by the amount of all services.

Comment: if you look at the % there is no single total which can get the % as descibed by OP

Comment: That is a great example. However, the percentage generated from the code with the above percentage query, returns 98% only. It does not add up to 100%. Is this a normal problem in databases when calculating percentages?

Comment: By  using Integer values, the digits after the dot are cut off (the counts produce integers and therefore the result is an integer; if you don't want that, you have to use `CAST (Count(ServiceName) * 100 as float)` in the %-column). Also, you may need to restrict the total count subselect by a `WHERE`-clause  if you have done so with the main select.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage is a count divided by the overall (reference) count. You have to use an inner query to get that overall count:

```
SELECT ServiceName, COUNT(serviceID) AS Services, 
FLOOR(COUNT(serviceID) / (SELECT COUNT(serviceID) FROM Tester_DW)) AS percent
FROM Tester_DW WHERE...
```

Depending on the output you want (that is, what your reference count is), you may have to add the WHERE clause (or parts of it) in the inner query as well.

Comment: if you look at the % there is no single total which can get the % as descibed by OP

Comment: @ughai My answer is a push into the right direction, and easily adaptable to the full needs of the original poster. As I said, "depending on the output you want (that is, what your reference count is)" ...

Answer (score 0):

Try with window functions:

```
 Create table t(id int)
 Insert into t values
(1),(1),(2)

 Select * from (Select id,
 100.0*count(*) over(partition by id)/ count(*) over() p
 from t) t
 Group by id, p
```